# how to iterate over entries in list while defining own function

Tags: python, pandas, list, function

I'm trying to defining a function with these goals.

- a DataFrame `df`
- a list of countries (which can be assumed to all be found in the `location` column of the DataFrame)
  `cl`
- a string (which can be assumed to be a column (other than location) which will be found in the DataFrame.`column`

The function should return the average value for the given metric for the given list of countries. in layman's terms. I want the function to pull every back every country's given value repsective to what `column` is mentioned. then `sum` all entries in the list and divide by `len`
if this is a list

`g7 = ['United States', 'Italy', 'Canada', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Germany', 'France']`

This is my code so far:

```
def countries_average(df,cl,column):
    average = []
    for country in enumerate(cl):
        x = df.loc[df["location"] == country, column]
        average.append(x)
        y = sum(average)/len(average)
        return average
```

it returns, instead, a row from the first entry in the list. when one of the entries in `column` are `total_deaths`:

```
[28543    127410.0
 Name: total_deaths, dtype: float64]
```

any help iterating over this list and adding to `average` list successfully.
I tried `range(len(cl))` but that didn't help either. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
def countries_average(df,cl,column):
    return df[df['location'].isin(cl)][column].mean()
```

Comment: This Doesn't return anything, all my ouyput returns is
`Series([], Name: total_deaths, dtype: float64)`

Comment: If your x is a numerical value, then it should work. Could you print x?

Comment: `Series([], Name: total_deaths, dtype: float64)`

Comment: Change "x = df.loc[df["location"] == country, column]" for "x = df.loc[df["location"] == country, column][0]" (add [0] at the end) and tell me what you get.

Comment: `IndexError: index out of bounds`

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly? It makes no sense that your x value was 28543    127410.0 at first and now it's empty.

Comment: I have copied as instructed. my number was never  28543 127410.0. it returned an empty list

Comment: I changed the original code, please try it now, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the edit it. unfortunately it returns:   `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Please join the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222316/discussion-between-ddd1-and-tktk and let's find a solution

Comment: I updated the code, it shouldn't give you any more problems now.